# What is the difference between seq and sequence in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lisp, clojurescript

Those following examples are producing same output.

```
(seq [1 2 3 4])
=> (1 2 3 4)

(sequence [1 2 3 4])
=> (1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: I think [this is answered](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/seq) [in the documentation](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sequence).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `sequence` always returns a seq even if the collection is empty (in that case an empty list), while `seq` returns `nil` for empty collections. Also, `sequence` can be used with [transducers](http://clojure.org/reference/transducers#_using_transducers).

A look into the source code:

```
user=> (source sequence)
(defn sequence
  "Coerces coll to a (possibly empty) sequence, if it is not already
  one. Will not force a lazy seq. (sequence nil) yields (), ..."
  ([coll]
     (if (seq? coll) coll
         (or (seq coll) ())))
  ...
```

So calling `sequence` with only a collection calls `seq` on the collection if it isn't already a seq and returns an empty list if the collection was `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

first of all, they treat empty sequence argument differently:

```
user> (seq nil)
nil
user> (seq ())
nil
user> (sequence ())
()
user> (sequence nil)
()
```

also `sequence` has additional arities to operate on transducers

as of docs:

> clojure.core/sequence
>
> [coll]
>
> [xform coll]
>
> [xform coll & colls]
>
> Added in 1.0
>     Coerces coll to a (possibly empty) sequence, if it is not already
>     one. Will not force a lazy seq. (sequence nil) yields (), When a
>     transducer is supplied, returns a lazy sequence of applications of
>     the transform to the items in coll(s), i.e. to the set of first
>     items of each coll, followed by the set of second
>     items in each coll, until any one of the colls is exhausted.  Any
>     remaining items in other colls are ignored. The transform should accept
>     number-of-colls arguments
>
> clojure.core/seq
>
> [coll]
>
> Added in 1.0
>     Returns a seq on the collection. If the collection is
>       empty, returns nil.  (seq nil) returns nil. seq also works on
>       Strings, native Java arrays (of reference types) and any objects
>       that implement Iterable. Note that seqs cache values, thus seq
>       should not be used on any Iterable whose iterator repeatedly
>       returns the same mutable object.